# Trying to nest a transpose formula inside an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TbPKehggzCGWy6LyEuzHZc5RouBHhyju35bqIGpInhM/edit#gid=14120435

I know how to transpose the data in colA (`=Transpose(A2:A)`). I know how to write an array formula to output the data i'd like (F1), but I'd like to nest the Transpose formula into the formula in F1 so that as items are added to colA, the table on the right populates with the header rows relying on the values in A2:A and the data as it is in ColF

Comment: Would be nice if there was a formula to work from to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: You need to show the problem you are having, in the question itself (i.e. it needs to make sense without the link). See [mcve]. Can you edit this so the link is helpful but not essential?

Comment: I am struggling to understand why you don't understand this simple concept. Of course the worksheet has sufficient information on it - but the question itself does not. From the link I supplied: _Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**_. That page is official advice from Stack Overflow on how to use the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(header,TOROW(A2:A,1),{header;IF(D2:D="",,E2:E*VLOOKUP(header,A:B,2,))}))
```

Or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(header,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),{header;IF(D2:D="",,E2:E*VLOOKUP(header,A:B,2,))}))
```

Comment: Seems as though the Google Sheets DEV Team has temporarily paused the use of TOROW. So, this formula currently doesn't work, as of February 18, 2023. Who knows when they'll enable it to work again.